# Add multiple events to the Calendar with Concurrency

Tags: swift, eventkit, swift-concurrency

I created a function to add my course events to the calendar app using EventKit.

After learning the swift concurrency, I want to update my code to make the progress much faster, namely using the detached task or TaskGroup to add these events.

Synchronize code without detached task or task group:

```swift
func export_test() {
    Task.detached {
        for i in 0...15 {
            print("Task \(i): Start")
            let courseEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            courseEvent.title = "TEST"
            courseEvent.location = "TEST LOC"
            courseEvent.startDate = .now
            courseEvent.endDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(3600)
            courseEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            courseEvent.addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .daily, interval: 1, end: nil))
            do {
                try eventStore.save(courseEvent, span: .futureEvents)
            } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            
            print("Task \(i): Finished")
        }
    }
}
```

Doing the same thing using the `TaskGroup` :

```swift
func export_test() {
    Task.detached {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for i in 0...15 {
                group.addTask {
                    print("Task \(i): Start")
                    let courseEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    courseEvent.title = "TEST"
                    courseEvent.location = "TEST LOC"
                    courseEvent.startDate = .now
                    courseEvent.endDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(3600)
                    courseEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    courseEvent.addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .daily, interval: 1, end: nil))
                    do {
                        try eventStore.save(courseEvent, span: .futureEvents)
                    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
                    
                    print("Task \(i): Finished")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the `TaskGroup` version:

```
Task 0: Start
Task 1: Start
Task 2: Start
Task 4: Start
Task 3: Start
Task 5: Start
Task 6: Start
Task 7: Start
Task 0: Finished
Task 8: Start
Task 1: Finished
Task 9: Start
```

Sometimes, only a few tasks will been done, and others will not, or even never been started (I created 16 tasks but only printed 9 in this example). Sometimes, all of these events can be added.

In my point of view, I have created **16 child tasks** in the `TaskGroup`.

**Each child task will add one event to the Calendar.** I think in this way, I can take the full advantage of the multi-core performance (maybe it's actually not. )

If I put the for-loop inside the `group.addTask` closure, it will always have the expected result, but in this way, we only have a single loop so the `TaskGroup` may no longer needed.

I'm really exhausted.

snapshot:
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8i8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time researching every aspect of the code. I found that the problem is `try eventStore.save(courseEvent, span: .futureEvents)`.

Alternatively, I use `try eventStore.save(..., span: ..., commit: false)` and `eventStore.commit()` to solve the problem.

I think this is caused by the data races because I'm using swift concurrency. While one event is saving, another one calls `save` method to save again, leading to data conflicts (just my guess.)

To solve this, luckily, we can commit a batch of events later using `eventStore.commit()` to avoid data conflicts. The result is what I expected !!

And after that optimization, the performance of this function is up to 25% faster (exactly 136ms faster). (haha. Perfect.)

**Final Code (in Swift 5.7):**

```swift
func export_test() {
    Task.detached {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for i in 0...15 {
                group.addTask {
                    print("Task \(i): Start")
                    let courseEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    courseEvent.title = "TEST"
                    courseEvent.location = "TEST LOC"
                    courseEvent.startDate = .now
                    courseEvent.endDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(3600)
                    courseEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    courseEvent.addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .daily, interval: 1, end: nil))
                    try eventStore.save(courseEvent, span: .futureEvents, commit: false)
                }
            }
        }
        
        eventStore.commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see all status messages that the tasks have finished you have to `await` each result and `print` it there

```
func export_test() {
    Task.detached {
        await withTaskGroup(of: String.self) { group in
            for i in 0...15 {
                group.addTask {
                    print("Task \(i): Start")
                    let courseEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    courseEvent.title = "TEST"
                    courseEvent.location = "TEST LOC"
                    courseEvent.startDate = .now
                    courseEvent.endDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(3600)
                    courseEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    courseEvent.addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .daily, interval: 1, end: nil))
                    do {
                        try eventStore.save(courseEvent, span: .futureEvents)
                    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
                    
                    return "Task \(i): Finished"
                }
            }
            for await taskStatus in group {
                print(taskStatus)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this. I wrapped all the code that creates my courseEvent into another function and return the EKEvent. I `await` for the result like you did, but cannot get these values (I have waited for a long time, exactly longer than 1 minute.)

Comment: I just tested the code successfully in a Playground. Do you have permission to access the store?

Comment: I have that permission. I tested it again. The for-loop will be execute 16 times ideally, which means there are going to be 16 events added to my calendar. But there is only 8. And it never execute to `for await taskStatus in group`, the console stopped at "Task 9: Start"

Comment: I have just added a snapshot, and you can check that out. [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8i8.png)

Comment: I have solved it by setting commit to `false` in the save method and later on calls `eventStore.commit()` method.